# Javascript: add the value of all objects in each array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

obj orders has items that each contain a value.

Example of orders structure:

```
   Array [0: Object { item: "shirt", status: "draft", "value":1 }] 
   Array [0: Object { item: "shirt", status: "failed", "value":0} 1: Object { item: "shirt" , status: "draft" ,"value":1}]
```

There can be multiple objects in each array, I will not know this.
How can I add the value of all objects in each array? I will then divide by the length of each array.

I have tried

```
 var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0; i< order.length; i++) {
      sum += order.value + order.value;
  }
```

Comment: Please post your data as json, not copying console output.

Comment: What have you  tried?

Comment: `.reduce((p, c) => p + c.value, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a1 = [];
var a2 = [{value: 1}];
var a3 = [{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}];

function f(a) {
  if (a && a.length !== 0) {
    return a.reduce(function (c, v) { return c + v.value || 0; }, 0) / a.length;
  }
  
  return 0;
}

console.log(f());
console.log(f(a1));
console.log(f(a2));
console.log(f(a3));
```